# Shell Scripting: Delete all instances of an exact word from file (Not pattern)

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to delete every instance of a certain word in a file. I can't make it so that it doesn't delete the pattern from other words. For example if I want to remove the word 'the' from the file. It will remove 'the' from 'then' and leave me with just 'n'.

Right now I have tried:

```
sed s/"$word"//g -i final_in
```

And:

```
sed 's/\<"$word"\>//g' -i final_in
```

But neither of them have worked. I thought this would be pretty easy to Google, but every solution I find does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$word='the'
$sed -r "s/\b$word\b//g" << HEREDOC
> Sample text
> therefore
> then
> the sky is blue
> HEREDOC
Sample text
therefore
then
 sky is blue
```

\b=word boundary

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you know if there is a way to use grep without an input file and output file? Just edit a single file?

Comment: what is your motive? .. do you want to output the matched patterns to an output file or use sed's substitution feature without printing output to terminal?

Comment: you can use grep with input from your keyboard and put matching lines to a file using: `grep 'pattern' > output_file` and if you want to substitute the string in place use `sed's -i` option for `in-place`  substitution `sed -i 's/pattern/replaceWith/g' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
# test
word='the'
echo 'aaa then bbb'  | sed -r "s/$word//g"

# To match exacte word, you can add spaces : 
word=then
echo 'aaa then bbb'  | sed -e "s/ $word / /g"


# to modify a file
word='the'
cat file.txt  | sed -r "s/ $word / /g" > tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt file.txt


# to consider ponctuations :
word=then
echo 'aaa. then, bbb'  | sed -e "s/\([:.,;/]\)* *$word *\([:.,;/]\)*/\1 \2/g"
```